# Wagtail ChoiceBlock dynamic default value

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I have a wagtail ChoiceBlock, thats dynamically loading it's choices from a function. My question is how do I set the default as the first value returned from that function?

```
index = ChoiceBlock(
    choices=get_blog_index_pages,
    required=True,
    help_text='Select a Blog Index to filter dynamic results'
    default=?
)
```